# d3.js: How to create custom colors gradient legend?

Tags: d3.js

I need to create legend with rainbow colours like [this](http://tactical.nekromantix.com/images/wiki/WRP_SurfaceMapLegend.png)?
But do not know how to do it. Any ideas?

**UPD:** Unfortunately i very poor formulated the task. I do not need just a strip with colors. I need a [scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales) object to create legend and apply it to fill SVG elements.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick `d3` implementation:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var data = [{
      color: 'white',
      label: 'Snow'
    }, {
      color: 'red',
      label: 'Rock'
    }, {
      color: 'purple',
      label: 'Pine'
    }, {
      color: 'blue',
      label: 'Basalt'
    }, {
      color: 'lightblue',
      label: 'Dog'
    }, {
      color: 'green',
      label: 'Cat'
    }, {
      color: 'yellow',
      label: 'Lava'
    }, {
      color: 'orange',
      label: 'Fish'
    }, {
      color: 'black',
      label: 'Sand'
    }]

    var width = 500,
      height = 150;

    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', height);

    var grad = svg.append('defs')
      .append('linearGradient')
      .attr('id', 'grad')
      .attr('x1', '0%')
      .attr('x2', '100%')
      .attr('y1', '0%')
      .attr('y2', '0%');

    grad.selectAll('stop')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('stop')
      .attr('offset', function(d, i) {
        return (i / data.length) * 100 + '%';
      })
      .style('stop-color', function(d) {
        return d.color;
      })
      .style('stop-opacity', 0.9);

    svg.append('rect')
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('y', 0)
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', height / 2)
      .attr('fill', 'url(#grad)');
      
    var g = svg.append('g')
      .selectAll('.label')  
      .data(data)
      .enter();
    
    g.append('line')
      .style('stroke', function(d) {
        return d.color;
      })
      .style('stroke-width', 2)
      .attr('x1',function(d,i){
        return xPos(i)
      })
      .attr('x2',function(d,i){
        return xPos(i)
      })
      .attr('y1',function(d,i){
        return height / 2;
      })
       .attr('y2',function(d,i){
        return height
      });
      
     
    g.append('text')
      .text(function(d){
        return d.label;
      })
      .attr('transform',function(d,i){
        return 'translate(' + (xPos(i) + 2) + ',' + ((height) - 7) + ')';
      })
      
    function xPos(i){
      return (width / data.length) * i;
    }
      
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Plnkr Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2OJ8J4t8rpXmX9mzSo8e?p=preview).